# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. >Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, compiler-errors, vscode-debugger

**Compile error of flutter code**

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'A:\flutterclass\source codes\ecommerce app\complete_flutter_ecommerce\android\build.gradle' line: 42
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > 'org.gradle.api.file.RegularFileProperty org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.fileProperty(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtPJ6.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**My project sample codes.But I don't know what is the error**

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.santosenoque.chatapp">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="chat_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Gradle wrapper properties**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

**build.gradle file**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.santosenoque.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName 
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}
```

**build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"


}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')


}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:chat_app/provider/app.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/provider/product.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/provider/user.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/screens/splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserProvider.initialize()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ProductProvider.initialize()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppProvider()),


  ], child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white
    ),
    home: ScreensController(),
  ),));
}

class ScreensController extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch(user.status){
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Splash();
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return Login();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return HomePage();
      default: return Login();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this isn't an answer!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is my project . But I don't know how to upload my project source code for this platform.

Comment: I am the junior of flutter programming so I watched the youtube videos.How to make the ecommerce app with flutter.I used vscode I pulled the github project source code and run it by vs code .Then got the error message.I don't have much knowledge of error fixing. here is the youtube link and github link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dy_zBF6rJFc&list=PLmnT6naTGy2SC82FMSCrvZNogg5T1H7iF&index=1                            https://github.com/Santos-Enoque/complete_flutter_ecommerce.git